# how to write a angular js directive for rendering jquery easy ui datagrid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-easyui

I am working on a angular js application and I want to integrate  jquery easy ui datagrid plugin .
The below code is easy ui code  to generate the datagrid from javascript.
I need to incorporate this in my angular js application. One way of doing this is to write a directive for this. Refer http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid12.php 
 Any pointers on how to write a directive for rendering a grid using jquery easy ui plugin?

```
$('#tt').datagrid({
            title:'Editable DataGrid',
            iconCls:'icon-edit',
            width:660,
            height:250,
            singleSelect:true,
            idField:'itemid',
            url:'data/datagrid_data.json',
            pagination:true,
            columns:[[
                {field:'itemid',title:'Item ID',width:60},
                {field:'productid',title:'Product',width:100,
                    formatter:function(value){
                        for(var i=0; i<products.length; i++){
                            if (products[i].productid == value) return products[i].name;
                        }
                        return value;
                    },
                    editor:{
                        type:'combobox',
                        options:{
                            valueField:'productid',
                            textField:'name',
                            data:products,
                            required:true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {field:'listprice',title:'List Price',width:80,align:'right',editor:{type:'numberbox',options:{precision:1}}},
                {field:'unitcost',title:'Unit Cost',width:80,align:'right',editor:'numberbox'},
                {field:'attr1',title:'Attribute',width:180,editor:'text'},
                {field:'status',title:'Status',width:50,align:'center',
                    editor:{
                        type:'checkbox',
                        options:{
                            on: 'P',
                            off: ''
                        }
                    }
                },
                {field:'action',title:'Action',width:80,align:'center',
                    formatter:function(value,row,index){
                        if (row.editing){
                            var s = '<a href="#" onclick="saverow(this)">Save</a> ';
                            var c = '<a href="#" onclick="cancelrow(this)">Cancel</a>';
                            return s+c;
                        } else {
                            var e = '<a href="#" onclick="editrow(this)">Edit</a> ';
                            var d = '<a href="#" onclick="deleterow(this)">Delete</a>';
                            return e+d;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]],
            onBeforeEdit:function(index,row){
                row.editing = true;
                updateActions(index);
            },
            onAfterEdit:function(index,row){
                row.editing = false;
                updateActions(index);
            },
            onCancelEdit:function(index,row){
                row.editing = false;
                updateActions(index);
            }
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution?